# Stop React JS / Flux application loading until one API request is done?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm using React JS with [Alt](http://alt.js.org/) (Flux) library.

At the very beginning I need to fetch user data from the REST API. When this request is not successful I don't want to render the whole application and display some error. If data are fetched successfully, rendering should continue. Fo fetching data I use [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) library.

How to achieve this fetch data test?

Comment: Just do a plain old axios request and wrap your react render in the success callback.

Comment: It seems that Axios doesn't support synchronous request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes the call up front then renders your app only if the call was successful.

```
axios.get('url')
  .then(function (response) {
    // success, let's render the app
    // you can pass the whole response object or just the data to your app
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MyApp reesponse={response}/>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    // something went wrong
  });
```